# Add colors to dimple.js bar chart based on value and add goal line

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, dimple.js

I have 3 queries.
1) How to add custom colors in a bar chart? In the attached image for example, I want to add different colors for Metric Pink and Blue. 
2) I want to show a horizontal line as goal/target value for e.g. at 3.0k on y-axis.
3) The chart should render the x-axis values in order of Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr which is not happening now. Please advise.[image]
`<div class="row">
    <div id="test" class="column">
        <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pink and Blue Distribution</h2>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var svg = dimple.newSvg("#test", 590,400);
            var json = JSON.parse('${rlog}');
            var data = [
                {"Month": "Jan", "Metric": "Pink", "Value": 200},
                {"Month": "Feb", "Metric": "Pink", "Value": 320},
                {"Month": "Mar", "Metric": "Pink", "Value": 200},
                {"Month": "Apr", "Metric": "Pink", "Value": 320},
                {"Month": "Jan", "Metric": "Blue", "Value": 1000},
                {"Month": "Feb", "Metric": "Blue", "Value": 2500},
                {"Month": "Mar", "Metric": "Blue", "Value": 1500},
                {"Month": "Apr", "Metric": "Blue", "Value": 3001}
            ];
            var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
            chart.setBounds(80, 30, 480,330);
            var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x",["Month","Metric"]);
            var y1 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
            var bars = chart.addSeries("Metric", dimple.plot.bar, [x, y1]);
            bars.barGap = 0.5;
            chart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
            chart.draw();
        </script>
    </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

http://jsfiddle.net/cmubick/n5x0gkdy/

1) custom colors:

```
chart.assignColor("Pink","pink");
chart.assignColor("Blue","blue");
```

2) horizontal line at Value = 3000:

```
var line = chart.addSeries("Line", dimple.plot.line);
    line.data = [
        { "Line" : "line", "Month": "Jan", "Metric": "Blue", "Value" : 3000  },
        { "Line" : "line", "Month": "Apr", "Metric": "Blue", "Value" : 3000  }
    ];
```

3) sort x-axis by month

```
x.addOrderRule(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"]);
```

Comment: About 2) solution, we have a small problem, the horizontal line doesnt touch the y-axis because of the values we mapped. How to get a line that just behaves like another x-axis at that y value?

Comment: Here is a SO question that seems like what you're looking for with the horizontal line, but I couldn't get it to work with your chart.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989320/dimple-js-straight-line-y-axis-over-bar-chart

Comment: In d3 you can add many more axes, but as far as I know only the first x and y axes can be visible.  Any extra axis is only for data reference.  Maybe you could draw another chart on top of the original svg... but that's a pretty big workaround

Answer (score 0):

For 2) you could use something like this below for adding horizontal line(s). I use the following code for generating rules (horizontal grid line)

```
            var rule = svg.selectAll("g.rule")
                .data(y.ticks(5)) 
                .enter().append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "rule")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d) + ")"; });
            rule.append("svg:line")
                .attr("x2", width)
                .style("stroke", function(d) { return '#f00' })   //return my own color
                .style("stroke-width", 0.5)  
                .style("stroke-opacity", function(d) { return 1; });  //you could return 0 for ticks where you do not want rules, or some other condition
```